# Local variable is not assigning data to global variable javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, global-variables, local-variables

I have a function which returns data to getDates(), after processing i want the data in a global variable but it's not working.

```
var bookedDates=[];
function getDates(result) {
     var bookedDates1=result.split(",");
     var bookedDates2=[];
    for(i=1;i<bookedDates1.length;i++){
        bookedDates2.push(bookedDates1[i]);
    }
    bookedDates=bookedDates2;
}
alert(bookedDates);

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "getbookeddates.php",
cache: false,
success: function(result){
    getDates(result);
//dates booked 
}
```

bookDates is blank in this case but it should be an array with ["21","22"].

Comment: Your function isn't being called.  Above the alert add a line `getDates(result);`, or modify your bookedDates definition `var bookedDates = getDates(result);`.

Comment: it is called from $.ajax() success callback

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @RohitMahto -- Please edit your question and include the code there. Don't post code in comments.

Comment: Still your alert happens before your ajax call.  Put the alert inside the ajax success function and try again.

Comment: calling outside the getDates() and after ajax request still gives blank response

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have done a very silly mistake.
You are declaring the function getDates which is taking a parameter result in it.
But you are not calling the function So the inside of the function will not get executed until you call it.

Try to add a calling line of a function.

getDates(result);

before the alert line.

Comment: question edited, please check again, thanks for response,

Comment: Alert is called before your success response, try to call alert after the response.

Comment: i want the bookedDates outside the function getDates()